# Why is this constexpr function not any faster than a run-time function?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, constexpr

I wrote the following code to test the time taken for a constexpr factorial to evaluate vs normal way

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

constexpr long int factorialC(long int x){  return x*(x <2?1 : factorialC(x-1));}
using ns = std::chrono::nanoseconds;
using get_time = std::chrono::steady_clock;
void factorial(long int x){
    long int suma=1;
    for(long int i=1; i<=x;i++)
    {
        suma=suma*i;

    }
    std::cout<<suma<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
    long int x = 13;

    std::cout<<"Now calling the constexpr"<<std::endl;
    auto start1 = get_time::now();
    std::cout<<factorialC(x)<<std::endl;
    auto end1 = get_time::now();

    std::cout<<"Now calling the normal"<<std::endl;
    auto start2 = get_time::now();
    factorial(x);
    auto end2 = get_time::now();
    std::cout<<"Elapsed time for constexpr is "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(end1-start1).count()
    <<" Elapsed time for normal is "<<std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(end2-start2).count()<<std::endl;
}
```

When I run the code I am getting

```
Now calling the constexpr                                                                                                   
1932053504                                                                                                                  
Now calling the normal                                                                                                      
1932053504                                                                                                                  
Elapsed time for constexpr is 81812 Elapsed time for normal is 72428
```

But `constexpr` should take nearly "0" time because it has already been calculated during compilation time .

But surprisingly `constexpr` calculation takes more time than a normal factorial to work. 
I have tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221716/g-c11-constexpr-evaluation-performance) question, but I am not able understand the answer in my  context.

Please help me to understand it.

I compiled the code through (filename is constexpr.cpp)

```
g++ --std=c++11 constexpr.cpp
```

#### **V2:-**

after @rici input, I did change line number 18 to

```
const long int x =13;
```

The results now are

```
Now calling the constexpr                                                                                                   
1932053504                                                                                                                  
Now calling the normal                                                                                                      
1932053504                                                                                                                  
Elapsed time for constexpr is 114653 Elapsed time for normal is 119052
```

It seems once I mentioned the x to be const, the compiler is calculating *factorialC* at compile time

I am using 4.9.3 version of g++ from MinGW32 on windows

Comment: Just calling each function once won't give much of a data point. Call it in a loop a few thousand times and print the average.

Comment: Furthermore, the two functions don't really do the same thing! Comparing them is close to useless unless they both do the same thing.

Comment: isn't `constexpr` really only guaranteed to be a compile time thing if you call the function with a constant, not a variable?

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Not really. The compiler is free to call it a compile time if it wants to. But if you use it somewhere where the value has to be known at compile time, it will be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Rakete1111, ok thanks. But even so, does the compiler ever evaluate it at compile time if the `constexpr` function is called with non-const variable?

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Oh, I see what you mean. Yes. But the value could also be a literal for example, it just has to be available at compile time.

Comment: Could the results that the OP is seeing be skewed by including the time taken to stream the answer thru' `std::cout` ?

Comment: @quamrana: Absolutely. 13 multiplications are a lot less work than converting the result of the 13 multiplications into an ascii string.

Comment: Downvoted for no information about optimization flags passed to compiler before you timed it.

Comment: Let's worry about correctness before speed.  13! is 6,227,020,800 not 1,932,053,504.

Comment: @Adrian McCarthy nice catch, 13! overflows the 32-bit long value.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Hi, I didn't worry about correctness of answer because both the functions are returning the same answer and obviously, it is an overflow .

Comment: @rici My assumption was constexpr will evaluate at compile time. **Suppose** the _factorialC_ was calculated at compile time then it should obviously take less time than the _factorial_ because during runtime _factorialC(x)_ is a value and _factorial_ is a function call and both should take constant time to convert to ascii string

Comment: @srinath29. I think it is being computed at compile-time, provided you are compiling with optimization, but there is no guarantee: the argument is *not* a constant expression (much less a constexpr) and signed integer overflow is UB, which makes the call not constexpr. But my point was that you are not timing the computation; you are timing outputting the value to cout. And compared wurh the cost of formatted output, the computation of 13! is just noise.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that something `constexpr` is *not* guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. The keyword `constexpr` just says that it *can*, but the compiler is free to evaluate it at run time too, as it sees fit.

The difference in run time is probably because you 1) aren't doing it enough (one iteration is nothing) and 2) recursion isn't as fast as iteration (I think, although the difference is minimal).

To guarantee compile time evaluation, you will have to use it in a context where the compiler has to evaluate it at compile time, something like a template for example:

```
template<unsigned long long n>
auto evaluate() { return n; }

//...
auto start1 = get_time::now();
std::cout << evaluate<factorialC(x)>() << std::endl; //factorialC is evaluted
                                                     //at compile timme
auto end1 = get_time::now();
```

<sub>There is also a standard library function for `evaluate`, [`std::integral_constant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant). You can use that instead.</sub>

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294271/forcing-a-constant-expression-to-be-evaluated-during-compile-time#answer-14297002 for a nice macro wrapper to force compile-time evaluation (that one based on `std::integral_constant`).

Comment: @DanielSchepler Didn't know about that, interesting thanks :)

Comment: @Rakete1111: gcc with optimization enabled does compute the value at compile time, but not without optimization, probably because it needs optimization to figure out that `x` (which is *not* a constant) has not been modified.

Comment: @rici That sounds plausible. Anyway, it is up to the compiler to decide whether it wants to evaluate it at compile or run time :)

Comment: Yup. But it is also reasonable to expect a good compiler to make a good decision. Anyway, i would definitely have made the variable const, and not only for the compiler's benefit.

Answer (score 2):

`long int x = 13;` That''s not a constant expression, so the compiler can't evaluate `factorial(x);` at compile time.

Try to send it constant values, like a `constexpr` value so it can do the evaluation:

```
int main(){
    long int x = 13;
    constexpr long y = 13;

    std::cout << "Now calling the constexpr" << std::endl;

    auto start1 = get_time::now();

    // Notice the use of a constexpr value here!
    std::cout << factorialC(y) << std::endl;
    auto end1 = get_time::now();


    std::cout << "Now calling the normal" << std::endl;
    auto start2 = get_time::now();

    // Simply call your function witha runtime value.
    // Try to ensure that the compiler don't inline the obvious value of x
    std::cout << factorialC(x) << std::endl;
    auto end2 = get_time::now();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time for constexpr is "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(end1-start1).count()
        << " Elapsed time for normal is "
        << std::chrono::duration_cast<ns>(end2-start2).count()
        << std::endl;
}
```

By the way, you should compaire apples with apples when talking about performance.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I realized that from @rici answer. After computing with _const_ varibale, it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that it can not be computed at a compile time, because compiler does not know nothing about a value of a `long int x` in this function:

```
 constexpr long int factorialC(long int x)
```

If you want compile time factorial you can use templates instead. Something like:

```
 #include <iostream>
 template<int N> inline int factorial(){ return N*factorial<N-1>(); }
 template<> inline int factorial<1>(){ return 1; }

 int main()
 {
     std::cout << factorial<13>() << std::endl;
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your valuable time. I wanted to know why constexpr was not behaving as it supposed to be (As per my understanding) so asked about it to improve my understanding

Comment: Hi! Actually I am not clearly understand what does `constexpr` mean in your example. Compiler should know everything about your function to do the `constexpr` from it for you. However, in your case compiler does not know the value of x, because it is not an `constexpr`. Hence, you can try to change `long int x = 13;` to `constexpr long int = 13;`, may be it could help. The same as said below by @Guillaume.

Comment: Thank you. I did the same and could see the changes. I have also edited my question to reflect the same. :)