# Pre-calculating in gcc-4.8 (C++11)

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

Testing a code in old `gcc-4.4.0` and `gcc-4.6.4`, compiler was able to apply a smart optimization and *pre-calculate* the result for `const` inputs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

const auto N = 1000000000ULL;  // constexptr is tested, no effect

unsigned long long s(unsigned long long n)
{
    auto s = 0ULL;
    for (auto i = 0ULL; i < n; i++)
        s += i;
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto x = s(N);

    auto t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto t = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t2-t1).count();
    cout << "Result: " << x << " -- time (ms):" << t/0.1e7 << endl;
}
```

`N` is a constant value, then compiler can run function `s` in compile-time and assign the result to `x`. (No run-time calculation is needed for `N`)

Results in different versions of gcc (and also a version of clang):

- The last version (*clang-3.4*) [result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/359204a44973dacc) (pre-calculated): `0.001532 ms`.
- The old version (*gcc-4.4.0*) [result](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7570484/952747) (pre-calculated): `0.013517 ms`.
- The old version (*gcc-4.6.4*) [result](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe7371c59b35387b) (pre-calculated): `0.001 ms`.
- The newer version (*gcc-4.8.0+*) doesn't calculate it in compile-time, [result](http://ideone.com/pXsRk8): `1313.78 ms` !!.

Question:

- **Is this optimization omitted in 4.8.1? Why?**
- Is there any compiler command/switch to enable it (if it's disabled by default)?
- <strike>If it's omitted, how can I force the compiler to do this pre-calculation?</strike>

---

*Note(1): I tested both `-O2` and `-O3` switches, no effect.*

*Note(2): Forcing, I mean compiler's commands and switches.*

*Note(3): Function `s` is just an example, it can be replaced by more complicated functions.*

Comment: Rewrite it as a template metaprogram: `auto x =  S<N>::value;`.

Comment: or replace `const` with `constexpr`

Comment: @KerrekSB: So, you say gcc-4.8.1 omitted that pre-calculation and I should do a metaprogramming?

Comment: It doesn't look like you do anything to force it to run at compile time

Comment: I didn't say that. I just said how you get a statically-computed value.

Comment: Clang optimzes your program ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/359204a44973dacc))

Comment: @MM. you shouldn't expect gcc to do it automatically when the language gives you the facility to do it yourself, then in a way gcc would be ignoring what you told it

Comment: @aaronman: All the optimizers for the past several decades would disagree.  Getting the same result faster by ignoring the way the programmer did it is practically the definition of optimization.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not saying I would complain if a compiler optimized it for me, all I'm saying is you shouldn't be that surprised that a compiler doesn't do something you don't tell it to do

Comment: @aaronman The surprise comes in when you consider that previous versions of GCC apparently optimised it. This looks like a regression.

Comment: In gcc 4.7.2 this optimization still happens. How about reporting this issue to the gcc developers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've submitted it as a bug. Yes, it's a *Regression* in version 4.8 which is fixed in newer revisions 5 weeks ago. Follow it here:

- [*Bug 58717 - [4.8 Regression] SCEV final value replacement no longer triggers*](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58717)
- [*Bug 57511 - [4.8 Regression] Missing SCEV final value replacement*](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57511)
- [*Fixed in revision 202168*](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=202168)

Answer (score 7):

You can FORCE it to run at compile-time using the new C++11 `constexpr` keyword.

First you must transform iteration into recursion (this requirement is removed in C++1y), for example:

```
constexpr unsigned long long s(unsigned long long n)
{
    return n? n + s(n-1): 0;
}
```

Or with tail recursion (still works well for run-time computation when the input is variable):

```
constexpr unsigned long long s_impl( unsigned long long accum, unsigned long long n, unsigned long long n_max )
{
    return (n < n_max)? s_impl(accum + n + 1, n + 1, n_max): accum;
}
constexpr unsigned long long s(unsigned long long n)
{
    return s_impl(0, 0, n);
}
```

(In C++1y, all you'd need to do is add the `constexpr` keyword to the existing implementation)

Then invoke it with

```
constexpr auto x = s(N);
```

Comment: The problem is `constexpr` functions have depth limit (N=1000000000 is big for them) and they're not able to act with non-constexpr inputs.

Answer (score 3):

The C++11 way to deal with computations at compile-time is the use of `constexpr`. Sadly, `constexpr` functions are somewhat limited in what can be done. In C++11, a `constexpr` function is allowed to contain empty statements, `static_assert()` declarations, `typedef`s, and `using` declarations/directives, and exactly one `return`-statement (I got temporarily confused because I was looking at the C++14 draft which has the rules relaxed). That is, you'd need to formulate your function recursively. On the plus side, if a `constexpr` function is called with a constant expression, it will be evaluated at compile-time.

Other than that, you might want to help out the compiler with its constant folding. For example, it could help to

1. make the function `s()` an `inline` functions.
2. declare `N` as `constexpr unsigned long long N = 1000000000ULL;`
3. make sure you use a suitable optimization level.

Comment: Thanks, and what about _"Is it omitted in 4.8.1?"_ I think that optimization was excellent and doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @MM.: I don't know why the optimization isn't triggered in gcc-4.8.1 but there are sometimes subtle reasons why a compiler doesn't consider an expression suitable for constant folding.

Comment: The problem is `constexpr` functions have depth limit (N=1000000000 is big for them) and they're not able to act with non-constexpr inputs.. on the other hand, clang is smart enough to apply my desired optimization.

Comment: @MM.: Well, it is fairly easy to split the computations and make sure that the depth is only logarithmic. Of course, in the specific case the easiest approach is to use the proper formula in the first place, i.e., to return `n * (n + 1) / 2ULL`.

Comment: Right, but the optimization itself is more important to see rather than this specific function, many functions are not easy to split.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this optimization omitted in 4.8.1?

It looks like it is gone. It is still present in 4.7.2 though.

> Why? 
>   [From one of your comments:] I think that optimization was excellent and doesn't hurt anything.

It is most likely accidental and the gcc developers don't know about it.

I can think of a good reason why I would want to at least provide an upper bound on this optimization. I got bitten by MSVC back in 2009: When I gave it a machine generated C code it was trying to optimize it and the compiler struggled with it for minutes. Obviously, it was desperately trying to do some optimization which should have been limited in some way so that the compiler wouldn't struggle for minutes over a 7KB source file. My point is: You may want to limit optimizations that can potentially increase your compile times too much.

However it doesn't seem to be the case here. I have tried it with fairly small `N`s and this optimization is not performed either.

> If it's omitted, how can I force the compiler to do this pre-calculation?
>   Note(2): Forcing, I mean compiler's commands and switches

I couldn't trick gcc 4.8.1 into doing this optimization. I will submit a bugreport if nobody says soon that it is a known issue or it can be enabled with some compiler flag.

Comment: I just submitted it to gcc.gnu.org as a [_bug_](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58717) -- I hope there's not an obvious reason which I overlooked and makes me silly for reporting it as a bug.

Comment: @MM. Excellent! And I have confirmed that the issue exists on [Linux 64 bit, 4.8.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c22ce6c4b6f1a94) also but doesn't on 4.7.2. We will see.